# Load balancing nodejs app

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, passenger, load-balancing

I am currently deploying an instance of nodejs app to server, for loadbalancing I am using phusion passenger, which I find really handy. Now I am wondering do I also need an nginx server in front of phusion passenger app, if I deploy only one app in my virtual machine. The reason I was confused because in almost all the tutorial it was suggested to use nginx with nodejs. However I am not sure what is the need of having nginx as I am using phusion passenger for load balancing and static file serving.

Comment: There's no hard dependency or requirement to use nginx with node.  Use any load balancer and architecture that works with the app you're writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phusion Passenger runs *inside* Nginx, so if you're using Phusion Passenger you're already using Nginx. There's no need to put another Nginx before it.

Comment: The only thing I am confused about, when I see the tutorial, it say passenger + ngnix. Also there is another option called standalone passenger. So even if I use the standalone version will it use ngnix? Also is passenger standalone version ideal for production?

Comment: The Standalone version uses Nginx internally. Standalone makes Passenger and Nginx act like an integrated whole so that you don't have to deal with them separately. Standalone is fit for production.

Comment: Think of Passenger for Nginx like a mod_nodejs for Nginx. It adds functionality to Nginx so that you can host Node.js apps on it.